# Enable button with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a button on a page with disable state. I need to enable it when I change a selection in  a drop down menu. I'm trying to do this inside CLICK function:

```
$("#myBtn").attr("disabled", "false");
```

... but it does not seem to affect it. Is there another way to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myBtn').removeAttr('disabled')
```

The presence of the disabled attribute disables the button - it doesn't matter what it's actual value is.

Comment: Setting it to `false` (not `"false"`) using `.attr()` works anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#myBtn').removeAttr('disabled');` or `$('#myBtn').attr('disabled', false);`